# Python pop dictionary list values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
{'dict': [['IE', '5', '-5'], ['UK', '3', '-9']]}
```

I wish to pop the list values that are outside of the UK, therefore taking the first value within the lists and comparing to see if it is equal to 'UK'.

I currently have:

```
for k,v in insideUK.items():
    for i in v:
            if i[0] == "UK":
                print(x) 
            else:
                k.pop(v)
```

I know after the else is wrong but need help!

I wish for the dict to look like this once finished popping values that aren't equal to "UK".

```
{'dict': [['UK', '3', '-9']]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested dict and list expression can do this:

```
{k: [i for i in v if i[0] == 'UK'] for k,v in insideUK.items()}
```

If you really want to do it with a for-loop and change the list in-place, you could do something like this:

```
for k,v in insideUK.items():
    for i in v:
            if i[0] == "UK":
                print(x) 
            else:
                v.remove(i)
```

But it is discouraged strongly to change the list you are iterating over during the iteration

Comment: for a reason why not to take the second approach, check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6260089/1562285)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to filter out based on the first element

```
>>> data = {'dict': [['IE', '5', '-5'], ['UK', '3', '-9']]}
>>> {'dict': [i for i in data['dict'] if i[0] == 'UK']}
{'dict': [['UK', '3', '-9']]}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it using my way instead of using list comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using the `filter` function:

```
d = {'dict': list(filter(lambda i: 'UK' in i, d['dict']))}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'dict': [['UK', '3', '-9']]}
```